# Store array of object of reference in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to store reference of two different document in mongodb in such way:

```
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user",
      },
      role: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "userRole",
      },
      isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
    },
  ],
```

But it store like subdocument. I want to store store like normal reference so that it will easy to populate and easy to find the reference in this document.

Comment: That schema should work, can you show examples of what isn't working?

Comment: Joe, I want to query it faster. It store data like this was:

{
users: [{_id: djgh6735686,user: hu686877,role: nfkyyiy77777},{_id: cdjhhj788,user: fhjrhh7788,role: 4686jfgjg}]
}

Now suppose I want to fetch or update user's 'fhjrhh7788' role, I need to loop through users array. Also, mongodb automatically creating _id field which I don't want.